# What is the difference between Chrome and Chromium in terms of web scraping and Puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, web-scraping, puppeteer, chromium

I have a working script that scrapes title using Puppeteer on the inbuilt Chromium installed in puppeteer module in node_modules.

However, I'm trying to deploy to Heroku and it doesn't seem like they have a buildpack for headless-chromium, so I'm tried to run my script on localhost using my computer's chrome installation.

Result: it doesn't work. It doesn't throw an error or anything, it just returns that the title string is empty when it isn't, as if the contents aren't being loaded properly.

It does that for firefox too, but I assumed that's because firefox wasn't properly supported. Chrome is fully supported (I thought). I'm using Chrome version 85. I read up on the article given in the docs about the difference between Chrome and Chromium (https://www.howtogeek.com/202825/what%E2%80%99s-the-difference-between-chromium-and-chrome/), and I didn't find anything that would cause Puppeteer to fail. Not that I know much about the inner workings of Puppeteer or either browser, but most of the differences was just like browser extensions and media formats and Linux security settings.

This is my code:

```
    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppet.launch({
        //headless: false,
        args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
        //executablePath: "/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable",
        // executablePath:
           "./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-782078/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium",
        // executablePath:
        //   "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome",
        // executablePath: "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox",
      });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      console.log(req.params[0]);
      await page.goto(req.params[0], { waitUntil: "networkidle2" }); //this is the url
      console.log("done waiting");
      title = await page.$eval("title", (el) => el.innerText);
```

Notice the list of executablePath options. The "google-chrome-stable" one is the one I use to test if Heroku is working. The "MacOS/Google Chrome" installation is the localhost Google Chrome isntallation. The "./node_modules/puppeteer/....../Chromium" is the localhost Chromium.

Of these, only the localhost Chromium works.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heroku, but is this the buildpack you're trying to use? https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

Comment: yes, this is the one. I'm using that, heroku/nodejs, heroku-buildpack-google-chrome, and heroku-buildpack-chrome-headless